# Installing 18.04.2 64 bit ARM on Raspberry Pi 3B+ nothing happening - system there but no network

Tags: networking, arm64

I have Raspberry Pi 3B+.  I flashed the ubuntu-18.04.2-preinstalled0server-arm64+raspi3.img.xz to a MicroSD card, placed the card in the Pi, watched the system build, but no network connection.  Sees keyboard and HDMI monitor just fine.  got the password changed just fine.  I did not encounter any installer script, nor anything like raspi-config that I have used on Raspian.  What did I miss?

Comment: If you have a wired connection, it will you DHCP and you should be conected. If you want wifi, you have to configure it. There is no special script for that

Comment: DHCP in enabled on my router and I have the ethernet cable plugged into the RPi.

Comment: You can try to run `dhclient` manually to see if it connects to DHCP

Comment: I typed dhcp and was told not found.

Comment: `dhclient` as mentioned above